# Convert an array of character code to a string with javascript

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

Imagine you are typing a Japanese sentence like "天気がいい", if you are using a qwerty you will need to type "tenkigaii". Then depending on the IME you will need to select a result for the correct words.

Is there a way to capture the typed sentence ("tenkigaii"), given the fact that user may type other unreadable keys like backspace, arrow keys, etc.

If we catch all the typed keys, the result may look like

`["t", "e", "k", "i", "i", <backspace>, "g", etc.]`

My question: Is there any library to convert this array to the final sentence ("tenkigaii")? Doing from scratch may take a lot of time.

Comment: You can you jquery key press event

Comment: Why not just have the user type in a (hidden) text field? Am I missing some extra context?

Comment: @qxz what did you mean by "have the user type in a (hidden) text field"? Imagine we have a text input where the user has to type Japanese in. If you are using a US keyboard, then you need some kind of IME in order to type Japanese right? As soon as you finish typing the sentence, you will need to type space or enter to finish the sentence, now the result will be in Japanese. How can we get the typed characters in Roman alphabet?

Comment: Why don't you have the user type the US characters directly in a textbox or `<input type="text">`? Then all the backspaces etc. will be handled for you. You could look for when the user presses space or something, and then convert the word the user had typed. What type of interface exactly are you going for?